# How to convert scid.eco file in scid _vs _pc to pgn file

Tags: pgn, scid, eco

Is there any tool or option in scid_vs_pc to convert the scid.eco file in bin/data directory to useful pgn file there is some code in gethub named eco2pgn.py but i cant figure out how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install python, then run the script from command line.

```
python eco2pgn.py scid.eco > your_scideco.pgn
```

`eco2pgn.py` and `scid.eco` should be in same folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but if you simply want a file of ECO data in PGN format then there is one freely available with pgn-extract on this page: https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/

Comment: thank you for your time replying my request  . the eco.pgn file bundled with pgn extractor is relatively limited compared to the extended scid eco classification i want the same extended eco pgn file :)

Comment: Understood. Thanks for taking the time to comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion script included with ScidvsPC, eco2pgn.py would need to be updated to run in python3. See https://sourceforge.net/p/scidvspc/tickets/63/ for the changes (easily made).

Answer (score 0):

I have added an updated version of eco2pgn.py that works with Python 3 here https://sourceforge.net/p/scidvspc/tickets/63/